# How to dispose scene.environment properly in three.js

Tags: three.js

The following function in my application should dispose an existing scene environment and then recreate it by calling another custom function.

```
function adjustAmbientLight(ambient_light) {
    ambient_intensity = ambient_light;
    const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
    if (scene.environment) {scene.environment.dispose()}
    scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene(new SetNewSceneEnvironment()).texture;
}
```

The function creates the new environment perfectly.

However, when I test by logging renderer.info.memory.textures to the console, I find that scene.environment.dispose() does not eliminate the associated texture. Therefore, the last line causes a memory leak because it creates and adds an additional texture each time the function is run.

Does anyone have advice for me on how to dispose of the environment texture properly?

Comment: Before disposing the environment you have to dispose the textures loaded

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I found that the culprit is the WebGLRenderTarget returned by the call to pmremGenerator.fromScene(env_scene)

Previously, I used the WebGLRenderTarget to obtain a texture that would serve as an environment map, and I disposed of this texture afterwards. However, it did not solve the problem because WebGLRenderTarget internally allocates persistent resources.

I needed to keep a reference to the WebGLRenderTarget and explicitly dispose it to release the internal resources.

Here is my final environment map creation function that properly disposes of internal resources.

```
function SetNewSceneEnvironment() {
    //create scene to be mapped
    const env_scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const roomMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { side: THREE.BackSide, color: "white"} );
    const room = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(), roomMaterial );
    room.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    room.scale.set( 40, 40, 40 );
    env_scene.add( room );
    const env_alight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF,Math.ceil(ambient_intensity*20)/10);
    env_scene.add(env_alight);

    //map the scene
    const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
    const renderTarget = pmremGenerator.fromScene(env_scene)
    const env_texture = renderTarget.texture;

    //dispose of resources
    room.geometry.dispose();
    roomMaterial.dispose();
    renderTarget.dispose();
    pmremGenerator.dispose();

    return env_texture;
}
```